# What is the $\lVert$ symbol?

Tags: quadratic-forms, symbolic-computation

I am trying to understand the quadratic equation below but cannot understand what the double bars stand for. 
$$\lVert W_L LP' \rVert^2 + \sum_i W_{H,i}^2 \lVert p_i' - p_i\rVert$$

Comment: Do you really expect people to click on a link to make sense of your question?

Comment: A pair of double bars on the left of a quantity and another on the right denotes some type of norm or absolute value. There are many, many useful norms, it will be defined earlier in the document.

Comment: @lhf, I am not sure what you mean, should I not post an example?

Comment: @Will Jagy, thank you very much I will look for the norms.

Comment: Either copy the equation or post an image.

Comment: @lhf, just uploaded the the image as I was not sure how to type the L after the first W

Comment: Much better now, thanks. Yes, it's a norm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely the double lines is what is called a [*norm*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29). We for example the standard norm $\lvert \cdot \lvert$ on the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
\lvert x \lvert =\begin{cases}x & \text{if } x \geq 0 \\ -x & \text{if }x < 0 \end{cases}.
$$
Or you have the norm (also denoted $\lvert \cdot \lvert$) on the complex number $\mathbb{C}$ defined by $\lvert a + ib\lvert^ = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$.

Note that both of these norms satisfy certain properties:
$$\begin{align}
&(1)\quad \lvert xy\lvert = \lvert x\lvert \lvert y \lvert \\
&(2)\quad \lvert x + y\lvert \leq \lvert x\lvert  + \lvert y \lvert \\
&(3)\quad \lvert x\lvert = 0 \iff  x = 0.
\end{align}
$$

Now in general if you have a [vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorspace) $V$ over the field of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$, you can talk about an (abstract) norm as being any function $\lVert \cdot \lVert : V \to [0, \infty)$ satisfying basically the three conditions above:
$$\begin{align}
&(1)\quad \lVert \lambda x\lVert = \lvert \lambda \lvert \lVert x \lVert \\
&(2)\quad \lVert x + y\lVert \leq \lVert x\lVert  + \lVert y \lVert \\
&(3)\quad \lVert x\lVert = 0 \iff  x = 0.
\end{align}
$$
Here $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$ and $x,y \in V$, and $\lvert \lambda \lvert$ is the norm on $\mathbb{C}$.

So some tend to use the double lines $\lVert$ for norms other than those on the real or the complex numbers, but it is really just a matter of notation.